# Pytest mock always passes

Tags: asynchronous, mocking, pytest

I have created a pytest class to verify a module, but for some reason it always passes!

As you can see from the test case, the assigned returned value in the mock is different from what is being asserted and yet the test case passes.  I tried different options and still I get the same results.

I do not know if the *async* nature of the method under which the test case being performed is what might be causing the issue.

Here is the test suite:

```
try:
    import mock
except ImportError:
    from unittest import mock
import unittest

import pytest

from asb_queue import AsbQueue


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('mocker')
class TestAsbQueue(unittest.TestCase):

    # TODO: test_asbqueue_get_messages
    @pytest.mark.asb_queue
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    @mock.patch.object(AsbQueue, '_get_messages.receiver')
    async def test_asbqueue_get_messages(self, mocked_instance) -> None:
        """ Verify a message can be retrieve from from the Azure Service Bus Queue """
        # Setup
        import asyncio
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        mocked_instance.return_value = ['']

        # Excercise - n/a

        # Verify
        assert AsbQueue(loop, False)._get_messages() == ['message']

        # Cleanup
        del loop
```

Here is the module (I've cut away irrelevant code for the sake of simplicity): asb_queue.**main**.py

As you can see the class *AsbQueue* contains a method *_get_messages* and inside there is an object by which data is being collected from an Azure Queue, it is here that I want to place the mock, I want to substitute the Azure Queue by the mock in order to mask away that dependency: *receiver*.

```
class AsbQueue:
    """ Azure Service Bus Queue Manager """

    def __init__(self, loop: Sanic.loop, test_environment: bool) -> None:
        """ Constructor

            :param loop: Event loop used
            :param test_environment: if True TEST environment will be used; otherwise, PRODUCTION environment
        """
        self._loop = loop
        self._test_environment = test_environment
        logger.info(f'[[{("PROD", "TEST")[self._test_environment]}]] ASB Queue')

        self._kill_fetch = False
        self._incoming_qclient = None
        self._outgoing_qclient = None
        self._set_interface()

    async def _get_messages(self) -> list:
        """ Get the messges from the Azure Service Bus Queue, if any

            :return: Queue messages, if any
            :raises AsbQueueException: If there was an issue due to
                Queue lock, Service Bus issue, Key Vault or something unexpected
        """
        try:
            async with self._incoming_qclient.get_receiver(
                    idle_timeout=Const.QUEUE_SHUTDOWN_TIME
                    , mode=ReceiveSettleMode.PeekLock
                    , prefetch=Const.MAX_MESSAGES_TO_CACHE) as receiver:
                results = []
                async for message in receiver:
                    results.append(message)
                    await message.complete()

                return results

        except (MessageLockExpired
                , ServiceBusError
                , Exception) as e:
            warning = f'ASB Queue: {e}'
            logger.error(warning)
            raise AsbQueueException(warning)
```

Here are the results (cut away the warning for simplicity):

```
pytest -l tests/unit_tests/test_asb_queue.py::TestAsbQueue::test_asbqueue_get_messages     
============================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1                                                                                                           
rootdir: /home/fbenavides/src/azure/iso-lib, inifile: pytest.ini                                                                                                                
plugins: asyncio-0.14.0, cov-2.10.1, mock-3.3.1                                                                                                                                 
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                            
tests/unit_tests/test_asb_queue.py .
======================================================================== 1 passed, 55 warnings in 0.31s =======================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT mix unittest.mock with pytest, so the solution is in two steps:

1. remove the unit test part and just leave the pytest part

   ```
    import pytest

    from asb_queue import AsbQueue
   ```
2. rework the test itself

   ```
    @pytest.mark.asb_queue
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_asbqueue__get_messages_test(self, mocker) -> None:
        """ Verify a message can be retrieve from the Azure Service Bus Queue """
        # Setup
        import asyncio
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        mocker.patch(
            'asb_queue.__main__.AsbQueue._get_messages'
            , return_value=['message'])

        # Excercise - n/a

        # Verify
        assert ['message'] == await AsbQueue(loop, True)._get_messages()

        # Cleanup
        del loop
   ```